# Rails inverse of Polymorphic association in concern gives TypeError: can't cast Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use the information [in this tutorial](https://rubyplus.com/articles/5091-Tagging-Multiple-Models-from-Scratch-in-Rails-5) to learn concerns with polymorphic associations. I have the following:

concerns/taggable.rb:

```
module Taggable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :taggings, :as => :taggable
    has_many :tags, :through => :taggings
  end

  def tag_list
    tags.map(&:name).join(', ')
  end

  def tag_list=(names)
    self.tags = names.split(',').map do |name|
      Tag.where(name: name.strip).first_or_create!
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def tag_counts
      Tag.select('tags.*, count(taggings.tag_id) as count').joins(:taggings).group('taggings.tag_id')
    end
  end
end
```

models/article.rb:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  include Taggable

  def self.tagged_with(name)
    Tag.find_by!(name: name).articles
  end

end
```

models/tagging.rb:

```
class Tagging < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :tag
  belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true

end
```

models/tag.rb:

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :articles, through: :taggings, source: :taggable, source_type: Article

end
```

The forward associations work just fine. I can ask:

```
Article.first.tags
#=> Article Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" ORDER BY "articles"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "taggings" ON "tags"."id" = "taggings"."tag_id" WHERE "taggings"."taggable_id" = ? AND "taggings"."taggable_type" = ? LIMIT ?  [["taggable_id", 1], ["taggable_type", "Article"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Tag id: 1, name: "Superhero", created_at: "2017-11-12 21:06:33", updated_at: "2017-11-12 21:06:33">, #<Tag id: 2, name: "Bat", created_at: "2017-11-12 21:06:33"...
```

But if I do:

```
Tag.first.articles
Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "tags".* FROM "tags" ORDER BY "tags"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
TypeError: can't cast Class
```

I've tried several variations on the associations in the `tag.rb` model but can't seem to find any that works.

Comment: You may need to stringify source_type in the Tag has_many association. `has_many :articles, through: :taggings, source: :taggable, source_type: "Article"`

Comment: YES! I knew it had to be something simple I was missing. Of course the error always make more sense when you see the solution. LOL If you want to put this in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The source_type in the Tag's has_many :through association needs to be a string:

```
has_many :articles, through: :taggings, source: :taggable, source_type: "Article"
```

Comment: I think this got broken in Rails 5.2 by some refactoring. And only for database adapters using prepared statements. In Rails 5.1 I believe it was not an issue although what I see is not related to act_as_taggable.